# How to convert long string into CSV using the export-csv plugin for HighCharts

Tags: javascript, csv, highcharts

**[export-csv for HighCharts](http://www.highcharts.com/plugin-registry/single/7/Export%20Data)**

This is the method I'm trying to use: `Chart.getCSV()`

Note I'm not using HighCharts ugly menu dropdown feature. Their `chart.options.exporting.enabled` is set `false` in our app. We have another button which exist in another component whose purpose is to create a CSV from the Chart.

According to the docs all I need is to call `.getCSV()` on the chart object itself.

```
return priceLine
.then(alertSeries)
.then(tagLine)
.then(renderChart(chart))
.then((chart) => {
    // const pricelineData = chart.get('series-priceline').data;
    // chart.options.navigator.series.data = pricelineData;
    const csv = chart.getCSV();
    const array = csv.split(',');
    console.log(csv)
    console.log('array', array)

    ChartExport.storeChart(chart);
    this.chartLoading = false;
    return chart;
});
```

The Chart object: https://gist.github.com/leongaban/62ae997e45a697002f699ae0515a1321

However when I do that, what I see is a 1 long string, if I do getTable() I see it in log out HTML, how would you convert this into a CSV? And then download it?:

https://gist.github.com/leongaban/0edc8fb40b500a40a06e548b35a2adf7

---

array `const array = csv.split(',')`:

https://gist.github.com/leongaban/9110d2e9df9e1bf469e7909e962ef315

---

Their `.getTable()` will produce this HTML in the console.log is there an easy way to convert this into a downloadable CSV file?

https://gist.github.com/leongaban/f60ea104b2528e7d5721dafc7be1c391

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ah so there was no help in their documents on how to do this, but I looked at their source code and found this:

```
/**
 * Call this on click of 'Download CSV' button
 */
Highcharts.Chart.prototype.downloadCSV = function () {
    var csv = this.getCSV(true);
    getContent(
        this,
        'data:text/csv,\uFEFF' + encodeURIComponent(csv),
        'csv',
        csv,
        'text/csv'
    );
};

/**
 * Call this on click of 'Download XLS' button
 */
Highcharts.Chart.prototype.downloadXLS = function () {
    var uri = 'data:application/vnd.ms-excel;base64,',
        template = '<html xmlns:o="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:office:office" xmlns:x="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:office:excel" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/TR/REC-html40">' +
            '<head><!--[if gte mso 9]><xml><x:ExcelWorkbook><x:ExcelWorksheets><x:ExcelWorksheet>' +
            '<x:Name>Ark1</x:Name>' +
            '<x:WorksheetOptions><x:DisplayGridlines/></x:WorksheetOptions></x:ExcelWorksheet></x:ExcelWorksheets></x:ExcelWorkbook></xml><![endif]-->' +
            '<style>td{border:none;font-family: Calibri, sans-serif;} .number{mso-number-format:"0.00";}</style>' +
            '<meta name=ProgId content=Excel.Sheet>' +
            '<meta charset=UTF-8>' +
            '</head><body>' +
            this.getTable(true) +
            '</body></html>',
        base64 = function (s) { 
            return window.btoa(unescape(encodeURIComponent(s))); // #50
        };
    getContent(
        this,
        uri + base64(template),
        'xls',
        template,
        'application/vnd.ms-excel'
    );
};
```

Sweet! So now all I have to do is call these 2 functions:

```
this.downloadCsv = () => {
    const csv = ChartExport.getChart().getCSV();
    console.log(csv);
    this.$close();
    ChartExport.getChart().downloadXLS();
    ChartExport.getChart().downloadCSV();
};
```

Now all I need to do is clear out the empty series and fix the time formats and rename the file.